# 2 Leds, 3 Pusbuttons Arduino UNO and breadboard

Tags: arduino-uno

So when i press button3 it's supposed to make led3 blink and button1 led1 blink
But when i press button2 it's supposed to make them turn off but it wont

Any ideas what might be wrong with my code?

```
    // C++ code
//
const byte button3 = 4;

const byte button1 = 2;

const byte button2 = 3;

const int led1 = 9;

const int led2 = 8;

const int led3 = 7;

int buttonPushCounterRight = 0;
int buttonPushCounterDominant = 0;
int buttonPushCounterLeft = 0;
boolean buttonState = 0;
boolean lastButtonStateRight = 0;
boolean lastButtonStateDominant = 0;
boolean lastButtonStateLeft = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(button1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(button3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
   Serial.println  (A0);

  int potValue = analogRead (A0);
  
  buttonState = digitalRead(button1);
      if (buttonState != lastButtonStateLeft)
      {
         if (buttonState == LOW)
         {
            buttonPushCounterLeft++;
            Serial.println("on");
            Serial.print("button pushes: ");
            Serial.println(buttonPushCounterLeft);
         }
         else
         {
            Serial.println("off");
         }
      lastButtonStateLeft = buttonState;
      }
  
  buttonState = digitalRead(button3);
      if (buttonState != lastButtonStateRight)
      {
         if (buttonState == LOW)
         {
            buttonPushCounterRight++;
            Serial.println("on");
            Serial.print("button pushes: ");
            Serial.println(buttonPushCounterRight);
         }
         else
         {
            Serial.println("off");
         }
      lastButtonStateRight = buttonState;
      }
  
  buttonState = digitalRead(button2);
      if (buttonState != lastButtonStateDominant)
      {
         if (buttonState == LOW)
         {
            buttonPushCounterDominant++;
            Serial.println("on");
            Serial.print("button pushes: ");
            Serial.println(buttonPushCounterDominant);
         }
         else
         {
            Serial.println("off");
         }
      lastButtonStateDominant = buttonState;
      }
  
   Serial.println(digitalRead(button1));
   if (buttonPushCounterLeft == 1)
     {
    digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
    delay (potValue);
    digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
    delay (potValue);
     }
  Serial.println(digitalRead(button2));
  if (buttonPushCounterDominant == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  }
  Serial.println(digitalRead(button3));
  if (buttonPushCounterRight == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    delay (potValue);
    digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
    delay (potValue);
  }
}
```

When i press button2 once it will turn off the 2 leds but it doesn't
Other than that i don't know what to do.

Please guide me through my code and or possible solutions would be nice

Comment: Perhaps adding some `Serial.print` debug output might show you what goes wrong. If still in doubt, please show that output as well.

Comment: Are the connections correct? Kindly check your connections and if they are correct, please let me know. I may check the code after that.